# How to search people by birthday?

Tags: c#, search, datatable

I've found this way, is there any other simplier?

```
       ClienteAdapter cliente = Cache.CacheManager.Get<ClienteAdapter>();
       DataTable dt = cliente.GetDataTable();
       DateTime dta = DateTime.Today;
        String dia = dta.Day.ToString();
        if (dta.Day < 10)
            dia = '0'+dia;
        String mes = dta.Month.ToString();
        if (dta.Month < 10)
            mes = '0'+mes;
        String aniversario = String.Format("{0}-{1}", dia, mes);
        dt = cliente.Get(dt, String.Format("WHERE dtNascCli LIKE '%{0}%'", aniversario));
        if (dt.Rows.Count>0) {
            String aniversariantes = "Aniversariantes do dia:\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                aniversariantes += ((dt.Rows[i]["nmComprador"] != null) : dt.Rows[i]["nmComprador"] ? dt.Rows[i]["nmRazao"]) + "\n";
            }
```

Comment: Two things:  Unfortunately, I don't speak Italian(?), nor do a sizable proportion of SO users.  If you could translate your column names into English, that might be helpful.  Also, when you say "search by birthday", do you mean "find all people in a table that have their birthday on a given day"?

Comment: Yes find all the people that are having birthday today!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ could get you started.

```
from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
where ((Date)dr["birthday"]).Month = Date.Today.Month && ((Date)dr["birthday"]).Day = Date.Today.Day
select dr;
```

That yields an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which you could iterate over with a `foreach`.

EDIT:  Incorporated bemused's comment regarding previous years.

Comment: Same idea but use: DateTime.Now.DayOfYear

Comment: @aquinas -- I think DayOfYear might cause trouble in the case of leap years.  March 1 is (I think) DayOfYear 60 in a non-leap year, but 61 in a leap year!

Comment: I even had leap years in mind when I wrote this. Not sure what I was thinking though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this:

```
DateTime dta = DateTime.Today;
String dia = dta.Day.ToString();
if (dta.Day < 10)
    dia = '0'+dia;
String mes = dta.Month.ToString();
if (dta.Month < 10)
    mes = '0'+mes;
String aniversario = String.Format("{0}-{1}", dia, mes);
```

Into this:

```
String aniversario = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd'-'MM");
// You *are* storing dates in UTC aren't you?
```

This doesn't change the fact that this isn't a good way to store *or* search for dates, but its a good place to start.

That's all I got, besides Jim Dagg's LINQ example.

Comment: why would you store birthdays in UTC? When someone tells you their birthday is Jan. 10, do you ask them if that is Jan. 10 UTC time? :)

Comment: Because it can be different days in different parts of the world at the same time, and birth dates (presumably, I'm only guessing) have a year in them as well.